# Prompt user for input using boxen

Tags: puppet, boxen

I'm completely new to boxen (and puppet) and I want to prompt a user for a password during set up.  I need to encrypt the input and add it to a config file.

I'll be using a template to generate the file, but getting the password is a little tricky since puppet wont write to console when executing code inside of a template.

I've considered doing this using a ruby or shell script to prompt the user and then store the password in an environment variable to use later in the template, but I don't know if this is the best or most secure way to do this.

Any suggestions?  is there a "best practice"  for doing this sort of thing with boxen/puppet?

Comment: I have a similar question over on the Boxen issue queue. No answer. Maybe you can add your voice there to see if we can get some guidance from the GitHub team - https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen/issues/570

Comment: thanks for the heads up...  I've added this comment to your thread, hopefully octocat can save us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hiera and encrypt hiera data using the hiera-gpg or [hiera-eyaml](https://github.com/TomPoulton/hiera-eyaml) backend

Other option is to use facter with [environment variables](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/override-a-facter-fact.html) FACTER_MYPASSWORD or [external facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.2/custom_facts.html#external-facts) under `/etc/facter/facts.d`